# How to make CSS changes without the need to flush all caches after each CSS change?

Tags: theming, 10

Core version 10.1.6 with an Olivero based sub-theme with a `style.css` file.

My problem is that CSS changes I make in `style.css` won't take effect until I flush all caches and this causes me to lose much time.

How to prevent this situation so to make CSS changes without having to flash all caches each time?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150160/discussion-on-question-by-ali-how-to-make-css-changes-without-the-need-to-flush); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have CSS-aggregation disabled there is a direct connection between your browser and the CSS files. You have to configure the browser not to cache the files or the webserver to add headers to tell the browser not to cache. This is common to CSS development in general and not specific to Drupal.

However, there is one thing Drupal-specific. Drupal adds a cache buster query string to CSS files that changes when clearing the cache. The main use case is for deploying CSS files. This system was not implemented for developers to clear the cache every time they change a CSS file.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! I understand that this cache buster query string is added only to the aggregated CSS file (if available), hence the need to flush all caches unless we turn off CSS aggregation. The documentation could have a re-orgnization and general edit. I hope you went though all of my responses to cilefen and Kevin below the question post and thanks again for finally clarifying that and giving people a solution !!!

Comment: For people not having aggregation enabled it's also added to single CSS files. To make it possible to deploy new versions, for example when updating a module or a theme.